# Side Menu icon style issue

Tags: codenameone

I've a sidemenu icon which when pressed has blue bg. How can I remove it? I've found out the side menu icon has "TitleCommand" as its uiid. So, I've bgtransparency to 0 and background to none, to that uiid in theme in all unselected, selected, pressed and even disabled. Similarly border is set empty for all styles in theme.res

Please have a look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/2zp8cLwGr2k)

Update 1:

```
FontImage notificationIcon1 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_NOTIFICATIONS_NONE, style1, 3);
Command notification1 = new Command("", notificationIcon1) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    }
};
notification1.putClientProperty("uiid", "smallCommand");
getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(notification1);
```

For the bell icon in the right, I have changed the uiid using putclient property as above. But I've only added a couple of commands for side menu icon to appear as below.

```
FontImage homeIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, style, 3);
Command home = new Command("  Home", homeIcon) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    }
};
getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(home);
```

However I am now sure that it is not the problem of uiid, since I've changed the uiid of bell icon command same as sidemenu icon command ie. TitleCommand but the bg color is not seen in bell icon command. And, the icon of the menu button using a theme constant is not customized. But I've checked the project where I've customized the sideMenuImage in theme constant & the problem exists there as well.

P.S when I was creating the project initially, I've used native theme and hello world(bare bones) template in both of the projects

Update 2: as per shai's comment

```
sidemenuDialog = new InteractionDialog(new BorderLayout());
sidemenuDialog.setFormMode(true);
sidemenuDialog.setUIID("Container");
sidemenuDialog.setDialogUIID("Container");
sidemenuDialog.getTitleComponent().remove();
sidemenuDialog.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Label("abc"));
sidemenuDialog.show(0, 0, 0, 5);
getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToLeftBar("", FontImage.MATERIAL_MENU, 4, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (sidemenuDialog.isShowing()) {
            System.out.println("close");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("showontop");
    }
});
```

It prints "close" in the output. The bgcolor still exists.

Comment: Does the bell command on the right side have that same background? If not then it's not the UIID but something else. Did you customize the icon of the menu button using a theme constant?

Comment: No, menu btn is not customized using theme constant. And bell cmd on rt side has not the same bg. Please have a look at update 1 above for more infos.

Comment: This is how the menu button is added: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.java#L1417-L1425 if you add a menu button in the same way does it express that behavior? What do you see when you select the menu button in the component inspector?

Comment: It works but the bg color exist. I've couple of projects and all have this problem. It has default color as its bg color(in both android and iOs device as well as simulator). Have a look at update above to see what I've done with the code of menu btn u've provided.

Comment: I just created a barebones app to test this and I only see the gray color of the ripple effect on Android and nothing on iOS. So what did you do differently from a hello world barebones app?

Comment: These are all the older projects almost 5-12 or more months old and I've updated the library through codenameoneSetting. I've newer version 4.0.3 now and I've checked recently but they don't have the issue. I'm desperate to solve the issue. Copying all the themes, images and codes in new project will be awful. Is there anything I can do to solve it?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's an older project since we haven't changed the barebones project. If you have the latest it should be identical and the only difference would be your code/theme. So create a new project. Try to reproduce. If it doesn't happen copy the theme on top and see if it happens then. Assuming it does then it's the theme... Now try looking through all the UIID's in the hierarchy with the component inspector to see which one is at fault, it should be easy because the blue color should be associated with one of them.